# Clustered, HA Distributed Transaction Manager

Tags: jboss, transactions, distributed, jta, high-availability

I'm looking for specific product/technology or any proposed solution for the following problem:

- I need a JTA-compliant transaction manager, that can enlist XAResources via resource-adapters and perform two-phase commit
- It should be transparently available in JBoss AS/WildFly
- It should be clustered with high-availability for

  - Transaction manager itself
  - Application server (JBoss) with applications as clients for TM deployed at AS
- As "clustered" I mean not TM clustering, but client clustering sharing the same transaction: e.g. transaction begins on one JBoss server, then continues on second and is committed/rolled back on third. So the underlying resource (Database, enterprise bus, messaging) see all the requests from several app-servers as ONE transaction
- As "high-availability" I mean that any component involved in transaction work execution could have a standby/hot-active instance that could complete/rollback work in case of main instance out of order. This include:

  - Transaction manager itself (it should not rely on one instance running, all transaction info should be replicated on-line within cluster)
  - Transaction clients (application running on JBoss instance which is processing transactonal call should fail-over on other JBoss instance in case of server outage)

I can't get the JTS catch in terms of work with XA resources (not in terms of work with saved transactional objects) and have not yet achieved any success in setting up JTS in cluster/HA. May be there is an issue that transaction could be managed by only one instance of TM and if it fails the transaction is buried until server restarted.

I don't know whether what I'm looking for is an utopia or whether I an not on the right way at all :)